# MATLAB Best way to extract data from text files and convert rows to vectors?

Tags: matlab

I'm having a lot of issues trying to extract the data from the [attached text file (`'scratch.txt'`)](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/61987/scratch.txt). My goal is to convert every row in the text file to a `1`x`n` vector where `n` is the number of variables in the text file row. I also need to make sure that every value extracted into these vectors is an 8 byte floating point.
This is what I have so far but I don't know how to convert what I currently have as the output into a matrix:

```
fid = fopen('scratch.txt');
tline = fgetl(fid);
while ischar(tline)
    disp(tline)
    tline = fgetl(fid);
end
```

Currently this is what I get as the output:

```
4   3       
1   10      
2   30
3   20
4   0
1   4 1 
2   1 3
3   3 2
1.e7    1.339   .5      
4           
1 5 3 4     
1       
7 5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str2num`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html) to convert `tline` into a numeric row vector.
Since you have varying number of elements in each row, you cannot convert your data into a matrix: matrix (by definition) has the same number of elements in each row.
What you can do, is store the row in a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/what-is-a-cell-array.html).

```
res = {};
fid = fopen('scratch.txt');
tline = fgetl(fid);
while ischar(tline)
    res{end+1} = str2num(tline);
    tline = fgetl(fid);
end
```